# Vitest flags ignored

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, vite, vitest

I'm using vitest in my Typescript + React + Vite project and cannot use flags when running the npm run test command.

I tried with --coverage or --silent without success.
When I set them true in the vite.config file, they work just by running npm run test.

```
import {defineConfig} from "vitest/config";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";
import VitePluginHtmlEnv from "vite-plugin-html-env";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), VitePluginHtmlEnv({compiler: true})],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        },
    },
    test: {
        environment: "jsdom",
        setupFiles: [
            "./setupTests.ts",
            "./src/__tests__/pages/private/setupPrivateTests.ts",
        ],
        globals: true,
        include: ["./src/__tests__/**/*.test.tsx"],
        silent: true,
    },
});
```

I think it depends on my local environment because one of my teammates can use them without problems.

I'm using Intellij IDEA on Mac M1.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-- --silent` to Arguments in npm run configuration?

Comment: @Oksana do you mean to run vitest -- --silent?

Comment: @Oksana it actually works! Thanks <3